# multiselect dropdown select2 not working with sweetalert2 and browserify

Tags: jquery-select2, browserify, sweetalert2

I have sweetalert2 with browserify and I want to add multiselect dropdown select2 in sweetalert2 but it is not working

```
Swal.fire({
      title: "Multiselect",
      position: 'center-end',
      closeOnEsc: false,

      confirmButtonText: 'submit',
      html: "<select class='js-example-basic-multiple' name='states[]' multiple='multiple'>                  <option value='AL'>Alabama</option> <option value='WY'>Wyoming</option>  </select>",

      preConfirm: () => {
        console.log("popup didopen");
        const login = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#title').value;
      });
```

Comment: You need to call `$("select").select2()` after adding the HTML to the DOM.  It doesn't seem like you've added this call yet.

Comment: A quick look at https://sweetalert2.github.io/ recipes shows possible `Swal.fire({ didOpen: () => { $(Swal.getHtmlContainer()).find("select").select2() }, dropdownParent: $(Swal.getHtmlContainer()) });`

Answer (score 0):

You need to intialise the select2 on your select after you open the Swal2 with:

```
$('#you_select_id').select2({dropdownParent: $('.swal2-container')});
```

Using the `dropdownParent` option in the select2 init will also make sure that the dropdown box will stay on top of the Swal2, I found that it will appear underneath without.

Here's a setup example that I've used and worked, with some validation:

```
let html = `
    <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="new_team_members" class="form-label d-flex"><i class="fa-light fa-user-tie me-2"></i>Team Members</label>
            <select id="new_team_members" class="form-select" name="new_team_members[]" multiple>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
`;

Swal.fire({
    title: 'Create New Team',
    html: html,
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
    confirmButtonColor: 'green',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
    preConfirm: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            let new_team_members = $('#new_team_members').val();
            // Data validation
            if (new_team_members.length <= 0) {
                // If input is empty, show error message
                Swal.showValidationMessage('Please select some options.');
                resolve(false); // Reject the promise
            } else {
                // Input is valid, return an object containing the values
                resolve({
                    new_team_members: new_team_members
                });
            }
        });
    }
}).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
        //Run function to create the team.
        console.log(result.value.new_team_members);
    } else {
        console.log('Validation failed');
    }
});

$('#new_team_members').select2({dropdownParent: $('.swal2-container')});
```

JSFiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dennisnd/tcw2fy4v/26/)

```js
$(document).on('click', '#trigger_swal2', function(e) {
    let html = `
        <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="new_team_members" class="form-label d-flex">Team Members</label>
                <select id="new_team_members" class="form-select" name="new_team_members[]" multiple>
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                <option value="4">Option 4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
    
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Create New Team',
        html: html,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
        confirmButtonColor: 'green',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        preConfirm: () => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                let new_team_members = $('#new_team_members').val();
                // Data validation
                if (new_team_members.length <= 0) {
                    // If input is empty, show error message
                    Swal.showValidationMessage('Please select some options.');
                    resolve(false); // Reject the promise
                } else {
                    // Input is valid, return an object containing the values
                    resolve({
                        new_team_members: new_team_members
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            // Do something
            console.log(result.value.new_team_members);
        } else {
            console.log('Cancelled');
        }
    });
    
    $('#new_team_members').select2({dropdownParent: $('.swal2-container')});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


 <button id="trigger_swal2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary d-flex justify-content-center mx-auto mt-3">
   Trigger Swal
 </button>
```